# How to count distinct Strings in ArrayList without using Set?

Tags: java, arraylist

How do you count the number of distinct Strings in an `ArrayList` without using the Set data structure in the Java libraries?

I made two ArrayLists, one stored and one empty and want to store the empty one with distinct Strings. What am I doing wrongly?

```
public void distinctCount (WordStream words) {
ArrayList<String> loaded = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> empty = new ArrayList<String>();
  int count = 0;

  // Fill loaded with word stream
  for(String i : words) {
    loaded.add(i);
  }

  // Fill empty with loaded
  // Catch collisions
  for(int i = 0; i < loaded.size(); i++) {
    if(loaded.get(i) != empty.get(i)) {
      empty.add(loaded.get(i));
    }
  }
  return empty.size();
}
```

Comment: Why the "no `Set`" restriction? You could add all elements to a `Set` then provide a `List` view of it. Also, "program to an interface"; prefer `List<String> empty = new ArrayList<String>();`.

Comment: I think you will have to scan the `ArrayList` for a duplicate before each addition.

Comment: @Jubobs Probably because it's a homework or an interview question.

Comment: instead of `loaded.get(i) != empty.get(i)` use `!empty.contains(loaded.get(i))`

Comment: And I suggest using a for-Each loop

Comment: sort and iterate comparing previous and current

Comment: Hey Naomi check my ans Using Collections.sort() and O(n^2) if its right please accept my ans

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very bad / slow option you have:

```
for(String s: loaded){
    if(!empty.contains(s)){
        empty.add(s);
    }
}
```

or if you are Java 8 fan:

```
empty = loaded.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing only corresponding elements. Meaning that you compare the n<sup>th</sup> element with the n<sup>th</sup> element in the second arraylist.

The straightforward solution would be having nested loops: for each element in the first arraylist, loop over *all* elements in the second array list, if no match found - you know it's distinct. This solution's complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Of course there are many helpful methods in the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) API that can make your life much easier. If there's no restriction on other data structures, you can consider using [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

use `map<String,Integer>`

If string exists, get the value and increment it, if there is no value against that key add 1 against that key.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Collections.sort()**
If all your list items implements Comparable, you can sort the list beforehand and then count successive items which are non equals.

```
private static int getUniqueCountUsingSort(List<String> list) {
    if (list.size() < 2) { // obvious case.
        return list.size();
    }

    List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(listCopy);
    int uniqueCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < listCopy.size(); i++) { // starts at 1.
                    // Compare with previous item in the sorted list.
        if (!listCopy.get(i).equals(listCopy.get(i-1))) {
            uniqueCount ++;
        }
    }
    return uniqueCount;
}
```

This method has the same performance characteristics as the Set method because Collections.sort() is O(n log(n)).

**By hand**
You can also simply do it the hard way, but it is slower O(n^2):

```
private static int getUniqueCountByHand(List<String> list) {

    int uniqueCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        boolean isUnique = true;
        // look if there is another entity before that is equal to this one.
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (list.get(j).equals(list.get(i))) {
                isUnique = false;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique) {
            uniqueCount ++;
        }
    }

    return uniqueCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loaded.stream().filter(w->!empty.contains(w)).forEach(w->empty.add(w));
```

As per suggestion in the comments.

```
List<String> empty = loaded.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not just `loaded.stream().distinct().count()`?

Comment: @marstran that is much better. I added it with a collect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map` if you don't want to use `Set`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
int count=0;
for(String str:words) {
   if(map.containsKey)
      continue;
   count++;
   map.put(str,0);
}
return count;
```

Count will give you number of distinct strings in Arraylist `word`.